# How to get record count based on based on some conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to prepare a report which will show month wise Count of orders where Ship-to address = Bill-to address
and Count of orders where Ship-to address <> Bill-to address ,
For Example

Year    Month   Same_shipbill   Diff_shipbill

2014    January 1768    1233

2014    February    1234    1222

and so on for the current year.

I have tried this query

```
SELECT  MAX(DATENAME(YEAR, order_date)) AS [YEAR],
        DATENAME(MONTH, order_date) AS [MONTH],
        COUNT(*) AS SAME_BILL_SHIP
FROM    x_master_order_tb O
         INNER JOIN tbl_Order_Addresses A
           ON A.addressID = O.addressid
WHERE   order_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00:000' AND GETDATE()
         AND wcs_status_id = 1
         AND A.ship_bill = 'Y'
GROUP BY    DATENAME(MONTH, order_date)
```

This query gets only the count where ship = bill address , not sure how to get the "Diff_shipbill" column values in this query?
I just need to flip the condition A.ship_bill = 'N'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to count both `ship_bill` Y and N like this?

```
;WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT
   MAX(DATENAME(YEAR, order_date)) AS [YEAR]
  ,DATENAME(MONTH, order_date) AS [MONTH]
  ,MONTH(order_date) AS MONTHNR
  ,CASE WHEN A.ship_bill = 'Y' THEN COUNT(*) END AS SAME_BILL_SHIP
  ,CASE WHEN A.ship_bill = 'N' THEN COUNT(*) END AS DIFF_BILL_SHIP
 FROM x_master_order_tb O
  INNER JOIN tbl_Order_Addresses A
   ON A.addressID = O.addressid
 WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00:000' AND GETDATE()
  AND wcs_status_id = 1
 GROUP BY
   DATENAME(MONTH, order_date)
  ,MONTH(order_date)
  ,A.ship_bill
)
SELECT
  YEAR
 ,MONTH
 ,MAX(SAME_BILL_SHIP) AS SAME_BILL_SHIP
 ,MAX(DIFF_BILL_SHIP) AS DIFF_BILL_SHIP
FROM cte
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, MONTHNR
ORDER BY MONTHNR
```

Edit: Added `A.ship_bill` to the `GROUP BY` clause.
Edit: using a CTE you can loose the NULL rows

Comment: ERROR: `Column 'tbl_Order_Addresses.ship_bill' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: also DIFF_BILL_SHIP always calculated to be NULL, WHICH IS NOT THE CASE

Comment: your query produces two rows for each month, first row for `same_bill_ship` correct value and `diff_bill_ship`  is null and second is the opposite. Can we have both the values in one row?

Comment: You'll have to `PIVOT` the values for that, or you can bypass that by using a CTE and 'grouping the NULLS'

Comment: Your query working now , I also wrote query using cte but bit complex than yours. Can we have sorting by month on your query?

Comment: Sure, just put `ORDER BY MONTH` at the end

Comment: But that will sort alphabetically.

Comment: Didn't see it was DATENAME. I added the ORDER BY clause and also in the CTE.

Answer (score 0):

you can put select clause in column list this can give you ***"same_bill_ship",  "diff_bill_ship"*** in same row.
See if this can help.

```
SELECT  MAX(DATENAME(YEAR, order_date)) AS [YEAR],
    DATENAME(MONTH, order_date) AS [MONTH],
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FROM    x_master_order_tb O1 INNER JOIN tbl_Order_Addresses A1 ON A1.addressID = O1.addressid
        WHERE   order_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00:000' AND GETDATE() AND wcs_status_id = 1 AND A1.ship_bill = 'Y'
        GROUP BY    DATENAME(MONTH, order_date)),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FROM    x_master_order_tb O2 INNER JOIN tbl_Order_Addresses A2 ON A2.addressID = O2.addressid
        WHERE   order_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00:000' AND GETDATE() AND wcs_status_id = 1 AND A2.ship_bill = 'N'
        GROUP BY    DATENAME(MONTH, order_date))
FROM    x_master_order_tb O
INNER JOIN tbl_Order_Addresses A ON A.addressID = O.addressid
WHERE   order_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00:000' AND GETDATE() AND wcs_status_id = 1
GROUP BY    DATENAME(MONTH, order_date)
```